# How do you use the phrasal verb 'rip off'?

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

Can I say 'rip someone off of [a sum of money or possession]'? Is this the right way to specify what exactly has been "ripped off" (if the object is a person or group of people)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No

"Rip off" as a verb meaning "cheat or steal" does not normally take an indirect object indicating what was stolen. It is not natural to write:

> He ripped me off of five dollars when he overcharged. [image: Red X for "do not use"]

"out of" is no better here. If anything it is even less natural.

> He ripped me off out of five dollars when he overcharged. [image: Red X for "do not use"]

If you want to specify what was stolen or the amount of the cheat, use a different verb such as "steal" or "cheat". For example:

- > John Stole Jane's bicycle. [image: Green check mark for "OK"]
- > He cheated me out of five dollars. [image: Green check mark for "OK"]

the verb "ripped of" can take the thing stolen as a direct object, instead of the victim:

> He ripped off my bicycle.  [image: Green check mark for "OK"]

In some cases this form can lead to ambiguity, The above could somehow mean "he stole from my bicycle" rather than "he stole my bicycle". Usual in context the intended meaning is clear. This form is perhaps more often used when "rip off" is uswed in the sense of "copied without permission".

> "He ripped off my song." [image: Green check mark for "OK"]

More information about a "rip-off" can be added by a clause following "by". For example:

> He ripped me off by charging ten dollars for a five dollar item. [image: Green check mark for "OK"]

But here "cheated" works as well or better:

> He cheated me by charging ten dollars for a five dollar item. [image: Green check mark for "OK"]

Also remember that "ripped-off" is very informal, and should not be used in formal writing.

Answer (score 1):

You have clarified in a comment that you mean *rip off* in the sense of "cheat or overcharge".

In that sense, *rip off* does not have an argument for the amount or object gained and lost:

> I was ripped off.

> He ripped me off.

> That car was a rip-off.

But I can't think of a direct way of saying

> He ripped me off ??? that car.

You might say *with*, or *about*, in the same way as you might say *He went mad with that car* or *I went to the garage about that car*, but these are vague in meaning, and only loosely attached to the verb.

Answer (score 0):

Generally it seems to me not very idiomatic to say "rip someone off of X".  I would prefer either "rip off someone's X" or "rip someone's X off".  It possibly depends whether you intend the literal meaning of "rip off" or one of the colloquial senses.

Using the literal meaning in an example sentence, I prefer either of

> The muggers rip off Jane's purse then run away.
>
> The muggers rip Jane's purse off then run away.

To

> The muggers rip Jane off of her purse

which sounds unnatural to my ear.

If we are using "rip off" in the colloquial sense of (poorly) imitating something, I would similarly say either "Movie A ripped off the storyline from movie B" or "Movie A ripped the storyline off movie B", but not "Movie A ripped Movie B off of the storyline" which doesn't work at all.

If we are using "rip off" in the (British English? Commonwealth English?) slang sense of a bad value deal, we do not specify what exactly has been ripped-off.  It is contextually implicit.  *"You paid £2000 for that broken old car?  Wow, the dealer ripped you off."*

Comment: No, no, I mean "to steal or overcharge". I think I know what my mistake was. I should've used 'out of' instead of 'of', shouldn't I?